# How can set Listener from DialogFragment to another DialogFragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have this problem in one Android application. I have a Fragment where, I can click on Button and I can display a Dialog Fragment with some EditText.
So, I have implemented a onFocusChangeListener on one of this EditText, and I can see another DialogFragment with a RecycleListView.

Now I want this: I want to click on one item of this RecycleListView and display this, in the EditText that have generated this event.

So the xml file where is the EditText is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="800dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="830dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">



        <EditText android:id="@+id/textAgent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="30dp"
            android:hint="Insert agent"
           />

        <AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/reaction_autocomplete"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="30dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/labelReaction"
                android:hint="select an option"/>

            <Spinner


</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

This is the layout of Another DialogFragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="830dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_list_row"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the principal Fragment:

```
public class AlertsDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    Context mContext;
    List<AlertValueSet> listValueSet_Description;
    List<AlertValueSet> listValueSet_Status;
    List<AlertValueSet> listValueSet_Agent;
    List<AlertValueSet> listValueSet_Reaction;
    ArrayAdapter<AlertValueSet> adapterAgent;
    View v;

    public AlertsDialogFragment() {

        mContext = getActivity();
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.alert_insert_dialog, null);
        builder.setView(v);

        builder.setTitle("Insert Alerts");
        builder.setCancelable(false);

        //spinner status
        EditText textAgent = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.textAgent);
        textAgent.setOnFocusChangeListener(new AgentClickListener());
        return builder.create();
    }

    public static AlertsDialogFragment newInstance() {
        AlertsDialogFragment f= new AlertsDialogFragment();
        return f;
    }


    public class AgentClickListener implements View.OnFocusChangeListener {
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus) {
                AlertsAgentDialogFragment dialog = AlertsAgentDialogFragment.newInstance(listValueSet_Agent);
                dialog.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(),"");
            }
        }
    }


}
```

This is the class of another DialogFragment that display the RecycleListView

```
public class AlertsAgentDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    Context mContext;
    View v;
    List<AlertValueSet> list;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private AlertInsertAgentAdapter pAdapter;
    //private OnRecurrenceTypeListener mListener;

   /* public interface OnRecurrenceTypeListener{
        void onRecurrenceTypeSelected(String rrule);
    }*/

    public AlertsAgentDialogFragment() {

        mContext = getActivity();
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.alert_agent_dialog, null);
        builder.setView(v);

        builder.setTitle("Select agent");
        builder.setCancelable(false);

        pAdapter = new AlertInsertAgentAdapter(list, new AlertInsertAgentAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                //recupero l'elemento che l'utente ha selezionato
                AlertValueSet alert = list.get(position);
                EditText textAgent = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.textAgent);
                textAgent.setText(alert.getDisplayName());
            }
        });
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(v.getContext());
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(pAdapter);



        return builder.create();
    }


    public static AlertsAgentDialogFragment newInstance(List<AlertValueSet> list) {
        AlertsAgentDialogFragment f= new AlertsAgentDialogFragment();
        f.list=list;
        return f;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be handled in way similar to how communication amongst fragments is done.

Create an interface in AlertsAgentDialogFragment class, implement this in underlying activity.

In onItemClick(), call method of interface using object of interface as shown below. Notice onAttach() method below.

```
public class AlertsAgentDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    Context mContext;
    View v;
    List<AlertValueSet> list;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private AlertInsertAgentAdapter pAdapter;
    private OnRecurrenceTypeListener mListener;

    public interface OnRecurrenceTypeListener{
        void onRecurrenceTypeSelected(String rrule);
    }

    public void onAttach(Context context){
        if( context instanceOf MainActivity){
            mListener = (OnRecurrenceTypeListener) context;
        }
    }

    public AlertsAgentDialogFragment() {

        mContext = getActivity();
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.alert_agent_dialog, null);
        builder.setView(v);

        builder.setTitle("Select agent");
        builder.setCancelable(false);

        pAdapter = new AlertInsertAgentAdapter(list, new AlertInsertAgentAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                //recupero l'elemento che l'utente ha selezionato
                AlertValueSet alert = list.get(position);
                //EditText textAgent = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.textAgent);
                //textAgent.setText(alert.getDisplayName());
                mListener.onRecurrenceTypeSelected(alert.getDisplayName());
            }
        });
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(v.getContext());
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(pAdapter);



        return builder.create();
    }


    public static AlertsAgentDialogFragment newInstance(List<AlertValueSet> list) {
        AlertsAgentDialogFragment f= new AlertsAgentDialogFragment();
        f.list=list;
        return f;
    }
}
```

I am assuming MainActivity is the name of underlying activity, then in MainActivity after implementing above listener, within onRecurrenceTypeListenercreate new AlertDialogsFragment passing this string in new instance.

```
class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnRecurrenceTypeListener{

    public void onRecurrenceTypeSelected(String str){

        AlertsAgentDialogFragment aDialog = 
            AlertsAgentDialogFragment.newIstance(str);
        aDialog.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "");
    }
}
```

Now update your editText from onCreateDialog().